# Webservice Orchestration for database sync

Tags: database, web-services, synchronization

I have two webservices, each service has its own database, one is master (A) and other is slave (B). If a call is made to  service B, it also calls A to sync A's database.

If for some reason A is not available, B needs to bring A up to date with its data at a later time.

Any suggestion on what mechanism can be used for out of process data synchronization?

Comment: You should consider thinking about this problem as a database synchronization problem, independent of the web services.

Comment: Sync is desirable from the webservice layer as master database is external to our datacenter and not accessible for database repliation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) could be useful to you - store the "missed" transactions and apply them later. You may have to do some trickery to work out which of the last few calls you made to A happened, and which didn't.

If A is updated from another source and you loose the link (rather than A going down completely), you may have a battle on your hands to resolve any conflicts. I'd recommend a [Temporal Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) of some sort to help manage that.

Alternatively, have you thought of using a messaging system such as MSMQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a master-master replication between 2 databases. We do this with MySQL.